# How do I update my software after installing a PPA?

Tags: ppa

I'm trying to install the latest version of Blender on my Linux Mint computer. The software manager installed an ancient version (2.69). I was advised to add this PPA to my system: https://launchpad.net/~thomas-schiex/+archive/ubuntu/blender

I followed the installation steps successfully. I also added the public key of the PPA after having an error message related to that. I ran the `sudo apt-get update` command.

But when I launch Blender from the launchpad, I still get 2.69.

How can I get the launchpad to launch a more recent version of this software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Iif** you ran `apt-get update` and **only that** after you added the respository, then you have not updated Blender, rather the references to it. To upgrade Blender, type

```
apt-get install blender
```

or even (better, if installed)

```
aptitude upgrade blender
```

and see if it fetches the version you expect.